# How to get the locator for an CSS ::after selector?

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

I have the following element (stripped for brevitiy):

```
<div id="searchButton">
    <div>
        <div>
            "Search"
            ::after
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which renders to this element:

[image]

I now want to click the dropdown arrow.

How to write a selector for this?

Comment: Do you have a demo page of that component? So we can try a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on Your CSS You can try this:

```
const element = await page.locator('div:has-text("Search")')
const arrow = await element.evaluate((e1) => {     
       return window.getComputedStyle(e1,':after').top
    })
```

This should return position and then use mouse click on coordinates, but its possible that this will return `auto` and in that case try to find property that You could use instead of `.top`

Comment: I am looking for a Java solution

Comment: Well according to official documentation:
https://playwright.dev/java/docs/next/api/class-locator#locator-evaluate
This should work with few changes

Comment: Ouch, my bad, sorry! Will check Monday, when back at work!

Comment: Needed to remove the "return", otherwise results in a syntax error.
It than return "0px". Atm don't see how this is helpful.

Comment: Try to replace .top with something that You could use. This depends on your CSS. Also another approach could be to use bounding box of search element:
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator/#locator-bounding-box